# addClass transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Seems like a common problem, but none of the answers i found so far work
Everything seems like a pretty standard and straightforward code, yet can't make the damn thing work.
Making a dropdown menu, and I need a hidden ul appear slowly on hover.

Html of it

```
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="wtvr">Title</a>
      <ul class="dropedmainnav t50 ">
        <li class="subnavli" style="position:relative;">
          <div class="superimage" style="position:absolute;  right:-100%;">
            <img src="" alt="{{link.handle}}">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="t50 subnavli">
          <a href="wtvr">Subnav link</a>
        </li>
        <div class="subnavsides"></div>
      </ul>
    </li>        
  </ul>
</div>
```

js of it

```
$(".main-nav ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){$(this).find("ul").addClass("dropedunderul");});
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){$(this).find("ul").removeClass("dropedunderul"); });
    $(this).find("ul").mouseover(function(){$(this).addClass("dropedunderul");});
    $(this).find("ul").mouseleave(function(){$(this).removeClass("dropedunderul");});
```

});

and css

```
.t50 {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -moz-transition: all 0.5s; -ms-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s; transition: all 0.5s;}
.dropedmainnav {display:none; padding:15px 0 10px 0; overflow:hidden;width:500px; }
.dropedunderul {display:table !important; min-height:150px; border-top:2px solid transparent; z-index:2; }
.main-nav ul li {position:relative;}
.main-nav ul li ul {position:absolute;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0); overflow:visible;}
.main-nav ul li ul li {float:none !important; text-align:left !important;}
```

I think that's about it for relevant styles.
I've also tried adding transition specifically to .dropedmainnav, .dropedunderul and i've tried using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the $.each(), wouldn't it be much simpler to call a function on each mouse enter/leave event and have it fade in/out:

```js
$(".main-nav ul li").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).children('dropedmainnav').fadeIn(500);
     }
 }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).children('dropedmainnav').fadeOut(500);  
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but you can certainly get rid of all this jQuery fuss. All animations and mouse-over effects can be done with just CSS (using `:hover`). Try the snippet below and feel free to comment if that is not related to what you want.

```css
body { font-family: arial; }

.onhover {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -moz-transition: all 0.5s; -ms-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s; transition: all 0.5s;}

li       .onhover { height: 0; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid transparent; }
li:hover .onhover { height: 20px; border-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div class="onhover">You are hovering item 1</div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div class="onhover">You are hovering item 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: which shouldn't prevent you to do the animations using CSS: it is more performant and allows you to better separate the view and the model. Now if it is somehow *required* you need to provide more code that shows why.

Comment: ok. tnx for the input. let me double check what i can do there with css alone